# How to remove a 'mesh edit' item in ANSYS Workbench?

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, meshing

I accidentally inserted a mesh edit item and tried moving a node, but now can't remove it. The context menu doesn't have any helpful options and I don't see any relating tools in toolbars. How to remove it?

Comment: There seems to be an answer already, but both your question and that answer would be improved by including screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  First right click your mesh in the project tree and then click "Clear Generated Data".  Then, right click, say your "Node Move", there should be a "Delete", click "Delete", then right click your "Mesh Edit" and there should also be a "Delete", click that.

Answer (score 0):

right click on mesh edit and generate. once it turns into green tick then right click again and there will be an option to delete